# Rendering UI elements in Shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am running multiple shiny apps in Shiny Server Pro. Each app is used by multiple types of users, that are shown different UI's. I found out that rendering complex ui elements via renderUI - i.e. when starting a session - is very slow when using Shiny Server (see https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1175 for more users having this problem). Locally - from RStudio - renderUI runs much faster.

The alternative is loading all ui elements directly when starting a process - so before a session has started. Since I cannot know which user is going to connect to a process before the actual session is started, each process will have to contain all ui elements of all types of users.

You can imagine that this behavior is not preferable (although this is how I "solved" it for the time being). Is there another way of loading ui elements that I am missing? Or am I just not using Shiny (Server) the way it is supposed to be used?

Thanks in advance,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `uiOutput` calls to only load the ui elements that are actually displayed. For example

```
server = function( input, output, session ){
  output$mainUI = renderUI({
    condition = input$showFirstUi
    if( condition )
      uiOutput( "firstUI" )
    else
      uiOutput( "secondUI" )
  })

  output$firstUI = renderUI({
    cat( "rendering first UI\n" )
    div( "first" )
  })

  output$secondUI = renderUI({
    cat( "rendering second UI\n" )
    div( "second" )
  })
}

ui = fluidPage(
  checkboxInput( "showFirstUi", "show first UI?" ),
  uiOutput( "mainUI" )
)

shinyApp( ui, server )
```

After starting the app, you will see in the console that the first UI only gets rendered after the checkbox gets changed. This is because `output` elements (as well as reactive values) use **lazy evaluation** which means they are only calculated and updated if they are actually needed for something.

Observers created with `shiny::observe` on the other hand will trigger right away when their dependencies change, so be careful with them if you want to have a good performance in your apps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gregor, but the problem with this solution is that when renderUI has to render a very complex ui (say, multiple pages with many charts and filters), it will take a very long time. My first solution was also like this, however this sometimes took over 10 seconds to render... Any idea how to improve this?